# Dynamic jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to create a dynamic jQuery code to handle an `.change` event with a list dropdown in drupal. I got it to work properly when hardcoding in the div id like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#edit-submitted-row-1-program").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() === 'DreamSpark Standard'){
            $("label[for='edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name'").html('Campus Name');
            console.log('Yes it is supposed to change!');
        } else {
            $("label[for='edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name'").html('Extended department name');
        }
        console.log($(this).val());
        }).change();
    }
});
```

This is supposed to change the label above one of the input fields *(as shown below)* if 'DreamSpark Standard' is selected.

However, what I want to end up doing is something like this:

[image: Dynamic line adding]

Where you can add as many lines as you need, and the event handler will change the label of the **appropriate** label.

I have tried the following code, but it is definitely wrong, as I'm just doing a `for()` loop when I know I should be doing a `foreach()` or something similar.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#edit-submitted-row-" + i + "-program").change(function() {
            var j = i;
            if($(this).val() === 'DreamSpark Standard'){
                $("label[for='edit-submitted-row-" + j + "-extended-department-name'").html('Campus Name');
                console.log('Yes it is supposed to change!');
            } else {
                $("label[for='edit-submitted-row-" + j + "-extended-department-name'").html('Extended department name');
            }
            console.log($(this).val());
        }).change();
    }
});
```

Here is the snippet of HTML code that matters:

```
<div id="webform-component-row-1" class="webform-layout-box horiz">
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-row-1--subscription-id">
        <label for="edit-submitted-row-1-subscription-id">Subscription ID <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-row-1-subscription-id" name="submitted[row_1][subscription_id]" value="" size="18" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-select" id="webform-component-row-1--program">
        <label for="edit-submitted-row-1-program">Program <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
        <select id="edit-submitted-row-1-program" name="submitted[row_1][program]" class="form-select required"><option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option><option value="DreamSpark Premium">DreamSpark Premium</option><option value="DreamSpark Standard">DreamSpark Standard</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-row-1--extended-department-name">
        <label for="edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name">Extended department name </label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name" name="submitted[row_1][extended_department_name]" value="" size="26" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

*(Each row will be incremented by 1, so the next row would be 'webform-component-row-2' and so on)*

**Keep in mind I can't add `data-` tags or extra stuff in the HTML markup as it through drupal, and I just have to work with the given classes and ID's output!**

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a loop, you can write a generalized code using the class selectors.

```
<div id="webform-component-row-1" class="webform-layout-box horiz">
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-row-1--subscription-id">
        <label for="edit-submitted-row-1-subscription-id">Subscription ID <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-row-1-subscription-id" name="submitted[row_1][subscription_id]" value="" size="18" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-select" id="webform-component-row-1--program">
        <label for="edit-submitted-row-1-program">Program <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
        <select id="edit-submitted-row-1-program" name="submitted[row_1][program]" class="form-select required"><option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option><option value="DreamSpark Premium">DreamSpark Premium</option><option value="DreamSpark Standard">DreamSpark Standard</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-row-1--extended-department-name">
        <label for="edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name" class="edit-submitted-row-extended-department-name">Extended department name </label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name" name="submitted[row_1][extended_department_name]" value="" size="26" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".webform-layout-box select").change(function () {
        var $lbl = $(this).closest('.webform-layout-box').find('.edit-submitted-row-extended-department-name');
        if ($(this).val() === 'DreamSpark Standard') {
            $lbl.html('Campus Name');
        } else {
            $lbl.html('Extended department name');
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Uv2h9/)

- To label added a new class called `edit-submitted-row-extended-department-name`
- We target the change event to the `select` element inside the `.webform-layout-box` element
- When it is changed find the `.edit-submitted-row-extended-department-name` element within the same `.webform-layout-box` and change its text

Comment: It looks good! However you seem to have added on a class to the label:
`<label for="edit-submitted-row-1-extended-department-name" class="edit-submitted-row-extended-department-name">Extended department name </label>` Even though I can`t add that class through drupal. How could I do it using the `for`?

Comment: I can edit properties, but in drupal, I can't add a class to that label, as drupal dynamically adds the label in :S

EDIT: I'll get back to you, I may be able to find a Drupal plugin to allow me to add in a class!

Comment: @RyanClarke will you be able to add a new attribute

Comment: Is there a way I can select the next label after the `Select` using something similar to what you suggested? I mean instead of looking for a specific class, could I just find the next label and then change that?

Comment: @RyanClarke if you are not able to add a new class http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Uv2h9/3/

Comment: @RyanClarke we can select the label with `for` attribute value ending with `extended-department-name`

Answer (score 0):

You should really look up

```
$.on and $.live
```

as they allow you to bind events for elements that do not exist yet. Then, after that you can continue working on elements.